# Set up field dependencies

Tags: arcgis-online, fields-attributes

I am creating a web map in AGOL using a single feature with multiple fields. My first field has 2 domains. Is there a way to have other fields grayed out dependent on which domain is chosen? I want certain fields to be disabled depending on which of the 2 domains is selected. I have tried using subtypes but am wondering if this is possible by setting up AGOL filters.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible but it is being planned https://community.esri.com/community/gis/applications/collector-for-arcgis/blog/2017/09/06/the-aurora-project